# Using SQL, find manager who's salary is double or higher than employee

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an employee table that has four columns.
Employee_id, Name, Salary, Boss_id
(1 Peter 500 2)
(2 Jerry 900 3)
(3 Mike 2000 N/A)
My question is, how can I find the manager whose salary is more than doubled of his/her employee?
For example, if my salary is 1000, and my boss's salary is 3000. I want to have the result as   "Me, my boss". If Peter's salary is 500, and his boss Jerry's salary is 900. That is not enough, so find Jerry's boss who is Mike. Mike's salary is 2000 and it's more than doubled. The result should be "Peter, Mike"
Not just for one person, I need to find such a relation for every employee.
The result I need should Look like following:
(Peter Mike)
(Jerry Mike)
(Mike N/A)

Comment: Why would the second result be "Peter,Mike" and not "Jerry,Mike"?

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: as the above comments, this is a very simple query with a self join and some simple math. can you show us what you have done as we may be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Join the table to itself:

```
SELECT emp.Name, boss.Name
FROM Employees emp
INNER JOIN Employees boss ON boss.Employee_id = emp.Boss_Id AND boss.Salary >= emp.Salary * 2
```

Comment: It won't work. This can only give one level. If the boss's salary is not high enough, you need to find the boss's boss. I need a query to do such a thing recursively.

Comment: Then you have to use a CTE (common table expression). I've done it, but not often enough to write here without a lot more sample data for testing.

Comment: I know how to write CTE but don't know how to fit the condition in.